# как сделать Добавление/изменение текста с последующим их запоминанием ботом. на pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

pyTelegramBotAPI не могу использовать другие библиотеки так как сделал уже много функций для этого бота.
Мне надо добавить функцию в бота с помощью которого можно будет сохранять текст от пользователя и еще + потом изменять этот текст лучше всего сохранять все это в .txt .
Пожалуйста если можете помогите)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В каком смысле сохранять текст? Чтобы получить какой-то текст от пользователя используйте @bot.message_handler или bot.register_next_step_handler, чтобы изменить сообщение используйте bot.edit_message_text

Если ты хочешь просто получать его сообщение и записывать, то используй @bot.message_handler:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def write(message):
    text = message.text
    
    f = open("writes.txt", "a")
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
```

Comment: я хочу чтоб когда я вводил например комманду /write Сегодня солнечно бот это сохранял в writes.txt

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: а как сделать так чтоб потом можно было изменять этот текст?

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. Когда пользователь пишет команду /write Вчера был шторм, вам нужно разделить команду и ее аргументы.

1-вый способ:

```
data = message.text
data = data.replace("/write ", "")
```

Вуаля, и у вас есть весь остальной текст.

2-рой способ:

```
data = message.text
data = data.split(" ")
data = data[1:]
```

Вуаля и у вас уже есть все данные, но в виде списка.
Вообще это делается встроенными функциями библиотеки. На вашей библиотеке я не писал, но использовал в более мощной aiogram. Там есть встроенный параметр args. Вы не и попадают все аргументы введённые с командой. Можете погуглить есть ли это в вашей библиотеке.

Comment: благодарю помогли)