# Поиск фото в интернете по запросу. Телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Как реализовать код так, чтобы когда я написал боту фразу :"поиск(постоянное слово для вызова определенного метода) фото(ключевое слово, по запросу которого будут найдены фото на эту тему) и мне бот отправил рандомную из всех фоток.
Я : поиск море
Телеграм: фото про море

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Будьте внимательны когда создаёте вопрос, возможно уже кто-то его задавал. [как сделать Добавление/изменение текста с последующим их запоминанием ботом. на pyTelegramBotAPI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1349468/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0/1349537?noredirect=1#comment2392259_1349537)